# How to access the cvSeq elements for finding the area of a contour using opencv 247?

Tags: visual-c++, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to find the area of a cvSeq contour, but I cant find the correct syntax for accessing sequence element.
this is the code that I want to correct. Could any one help me?

```
  for (int i = 0; i < contours->elem_size; i++)       // iterate through each contour.
  {
      double a = contourArea(contours[i], false);     //  Find the area of contour
      if (a > largest_area) {
          largest_area = a;
          largest_contour_index = i;                  // Store the index of largest contour
          bounding_rect = boundingRect(contours[i]);  // Find the bounding rectangle for biggest     contour
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I'm assuming you've used [cvFindContours](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours) to get list of contours in your example.

The [CvSeq](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/dynamic_structures.html#cvseq) struct pointer `contours` in your example code points to the first contour in a "Dynamically growing sequence". The `elem_size` you're assuming is the number of contours in the list of contours is instead the size of each element in the list. From the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/dynamic_structures.html#cvseq):

> int **elem_size**
>
> size of each sequence element in bytes

Instead the number of elements in the sequence is given by:

> int **total**
>
> the number of sequence elements

There are at least two ways to iterate over the sequence of contours:

## As an array

```
for (int i = 0; i < contours->total; i += contours->elem_size)
{
    double a = contourArea(contours[i], false);
    if (a > largest_area)
    {
        largest_area = a;
        largest_contour_index = i;
        bounding_rect = boundingRect(contours[i]);
    }
}
```

## As a linked list

Note! This assumes you've used the mode **CV_RETR_LIST** (retrieves all of the contours without establishing any hierarchical relationships) when calling [cvFindContours](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours). If not, the result might instead be stored in a tree and needs to be traversed accordingly.

```
CvSeq *it = contours;

while (it)
{
    double a = contourArea(it, false);
    if (a > largest_area)
    {
        largest_area = a;
        largest_contour_index = i;
        bounding_rect = boundingRect(it);
    }
    it = it->h_next;
}
```